# scrollTop() returns 0 in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, scrolltop, document-body

Not sure if there's another question regarding this, if so I apologize and please don't release the hounds.

Using the html5 doctype and doing a quick console.log off my scroll listener that tells me the value of scrollTop() value. I'm basically doing this so when I scroll past a point, I change the opacity of an element. I'm doing this using an MVS solution and I don't have the ability to push this to an external site so you can look. Here's a quick snippet:

```
var opacity = 1;
var scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();
if (scrollTop > 200) {
   opacity = 0.1;
}
$('#element).css('opacity', opacity);
```

If I scroll in Chrome, I get a console.log(scrollTop); displaying what I want (ie; 100 for each scroll I do) and my opacity disappears after I hit 200 scrollTop. If I scroll in FF and IE7+ the var returns "0" each scroll. If I change $('body').scrollTop() to $('document').scrollTop(); then I get a "null" return on scroll.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: `$('document')` should be `$(document)`, not sure how that affects your question though.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try to use `var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();`

Answer (score 17):

`$(window).scrollTop()` works as expected in both Firefox and Chrome.

For verification run the following jsfiddle in both chrome and firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/RBBw5/6/

Comment: its actually the right answer. $(document).scrollTop() tend not to works depending on the size of the body or others externals behaviors

Answer (score 1):

After some frustration with IE9 in quirks mode, I've found the that `$('body').scrollTop()` works reliably in IE9, Chrome 32 and Firefox 26.

Answer (score 0):

Use var `scrollTop = $('html').scrollTop();` works for FireFox

You'll need to sniff the browser out though (I know, feature detect, not sniff, but you can't detect this), because it won't work in Chrome, try here :

[Easiest/Lightest Replacement For Browser Detection jQuery 1.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365725/easiest-lightest-replacement-for-browser-detection-jquery-1-9)