# TypeError: a.browser is undefined for jquery.min

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a highcharts Pie chart that I am running through some tests. I noticed a reacurring error of:

```
TypeError: a.browser is undefined

...loseSpeed:"fast",effect:"default",fixed:!a.browser.msie||a.browser.version>6,lef...      http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/tiny/jquery.tools.min.js
```

what is causing this error? here are my imports.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/css/graphs.css" type="text/css"/>
<link REL="stylesheet" href="/site/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site/js/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Comment: The browser sniffing portion of jQuery was deprecated in jQuery 2+ (I believe). You can still use it, but it is now a separate download, and you will need a separate script include for it.

Comment: According to their [compability doc](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility) they haven't tested compatiblity with jquery 2.1.4 ; that might be your problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what `browser sniffing portion` are you referring?

Comment: @PT_C See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365725/easiest-lightest-replacement-for-browser-detection-jquery-1-9

Comment: Use the jquery 1.11.x, becuase 2.1.4 is not suported by old ie.

Comment: @SebastianBochan the error is in all browsers

Comment: Recreate your chart as live demo on jsfiddle, please