# CSS in Javascript JQuery - Multiple Transforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

I'm new to Javascript and I'm having problems with this:

```
$video.css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg) translateY(' + $body.scrollTop() + 'px)'
});
```

Only the roation works but not the translateY. So, what I want is to have multiple transforms in there. A usual CSS code would be like:

```
transform: rotate(10deg) translateY(10px);
```

What am I doing wrong? Probably missing some symbols.

Comment: Can you please add fiddle of your example

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvz1paf5/
So this would be it without translateY.

Comment: So what is the problem. It appears to do both in Chrome. I reversed the order for this one to keep it onscreen: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Lvz1paf5/2/

Comment: Oh well, it works! Uh I have no idea what I did wrong. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Seems like it's not working in Firefox though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$video.css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg),
    'transform': translateY(' + $body.scrollTop() + 'px)' 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[The problem with firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12941150/1492578) is that `$body.scrollTop()` returns 0. Use `$(window).scrollTop()` instead.

```js
var $video = $('.video'),
  $body = $(document.body),
  $window = $(window),
  bodyHeight = $body.height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  // Use $(window) instead of $(document.body)
  $video.css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + ($window.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg) ' +
                 'translateY(' + $window.scrollTop() + 'px)'
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
  margin: 0;
}
.video {
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="video"></div>
</body>
```