# How to return scrollTop value for scroll event inside scrollable HTML element on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop, microsoft-edge

So I have the following CSS on HTML and BODY elements

```
 html{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;    
}
body{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

it's important to keep this CSS to avoid fixed positioned elements from jittering on ie 9 and above

So basically the  element is a scrollable element and window.scrollTop() returns 0 regardless of where I scroll on the page so I've implemented this JS just for ie/edge browser clients

```
$('body').scroll(function(){

        var wrapHeight = element_to_stick_to_header.outerHeight();

        //The following condition is never true because $('body').scrollTop()
        // always returns 0 on ME

        if($('body').scrollTop() + headerHeight > orginalOffset  &&  window.innerWidth > 768){

             // do something 
        }
        else {
             // do something else
        }
});
```

This function works perfectly on ie9 and above but on Microsoft Edge it doesn't

I have tried the following so far to tackle this issue and none of the bellow seems to work:

```
var top = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || 
          document.body.scrollTop;
```

from: [This overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717252/document-body-scrolltop-is-always-0-in-ie-even-when-scrolling)

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

from [this overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633221/document-body-scrolltop-firefox-returns-0-only-js)

and

```
var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
```

from [this overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941150/scrolltop-returns-0-in-firefox-but-not-in-chrome)